# Posting Form data in MVC

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, forms

Hi I'm trying to post the contents of a select control in a form to an MVC controller. When I post the data it bypasses the model.isvalid code block.
Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong?

The action in my controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "Id,SignatureStream,LogoStream,CompanyHeader,MasterAccount,Name,AccountType,NoReporting,Prefix,Permissions")] UserSettingsViewModel userSettingsViewModel)
```

The view model:

```
    public IList<Permission> Permissions { get; set; }
    [Required]

    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public byte[] SignatureStream { get; set; }
    public byte[] LogoStream { get; set; }
    public String CompanyHeader { get; set; }
    public Guid? MasterAccount { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public int? AccountType { get; set; }
    public bool? NoReporting { get; set; }
    public String Prefix { get; set; }
```

The select control in my CHTML (with some angular):

```
    <select multiple hidden name="Permissions" id="Permissions">

        <option selected ng-repeat="permission in Permissions track by $id($index)" value="{{permission.PermissionName}}">{{permission.SatelliteAccount}}</option>

    </select>
```

Screenshot form fiddler:

[image: FormData]

Comment: Property `Permissions` is a collection of complex objects. you cannot bind a `<select>` to a collection of complex objects. The property your binding to needs to be `string[]`. And what validation are your expecting?

Comment: And why are you using a `[Bind]` attribute when your using a view model?

Comment: @johnnygrimes What exactly you mean by "bypasses the model.isvalid code block" ? You mean the code before and after that block is executing? If yes, clean and rebuild your solution, latest debug symbols might not have loaded correctly.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Good point on the [Bind] attribute, I've just switched from the original model to a viewmodel and didn't think to remove the bind attribute.